# How can one "smoke ship's?"

Tags: meaning, expressions

> Sherlock Holmes seemed delighted at the idea of sharing his rooms with
>   me. "I have my eye on a suite in Baker Street," he said, "which would
>   suit us down to the ground. You don't mind the smell of strong
>   tobacco, I hope?"
>
> "I always smoke 'ship's' myself," I answered.

-- [*A Study in Scarlet*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Study_in_Scarlet/Part_1/Chapter_1), 1887

I don't suppose that Doctor Watson, whatever his other talents, was actually smoking pieces of watercrafts. So what does the expression mean?

Comment: [This](https://www.johnhwatsonsociety.com/dr-watsons-ships/) might provide an answer.

Comment: The [John H Watson society](https://www.johnhwatsonsociety.com/dr-watsons-ships/) suggests eight possible explanations.

Comment: Yep, just found it myself. Thanks anyway. Unless someone comes up with something to add too it, I'd probably have to quote that page and consider it the right answer.

Comment: [Ship's tobacco](https://www.reed.edu/formosa/texts/Dodd1885.html) is also referred to in paragraph 13 of the linked article.

Comment: Ship, is/was also a popular name for matches. Just an aside.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here’s a description of “ship’s tobacco” by a turn-of-the-century chaplain in the Royal Navy:

> Most people who take any interest in “ships and the sea” have heard of “ship’s tobacco.” It is indeed difficult to imagine a sailor who doesn’t smoke, though, as a matter of fact, there are a considerable number of non-smokers amongst us, and a still larger number who prefer trifling with a cigarette to an honest pipe of “ship’s”. Some of my readers may have seen our Navy tobacco as prepared by the men themselves, a solid block covered with canvas, round which spun-yarn is wound in such a way as to make it like a miniature torpedo. The process of preparation is something of this kind : The tobacco, being served out in the leaf, is first of all wetted, and wrapped up in a bit of ship’s canvas ; then a line of tarry cord is fastened up at some convenient spot on the deck, and, by a mystic process which I never quite followed, the sailor, astride across this line, works it round the canvas tightly, until the latter is completely covered and the tobacco pressed into the orthodox form. In a short time it is ready for use, and may be sliced off or shredded off with the sailor’s jack-knife as required. The strength or mildness of the tobacco depends a good deal on the amount of saltpeter used to preserve the leaves. Those who like a “full” flavor are careful to retain as much of the saltpeter as possible ; a “medium” flavor is obtained by judicious washing ; while the “mild” form may be reached by a thorough cleansing of the leaves. As smoked by the bluejackets it is decidedly “full.”
>
> — Rev. George Goodenough, RN, [*The Handy Man Afloat and Ashore*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5P8KAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22ship%27s+tobacco%22&source=bl&ots=G03NpW4nVC&sig=0p6fIFYPDOrXSKOrbG2-_NeLXEM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiws62b7f7dAhWKyVMKHQSgCZsQ6AEwCXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ship%27s%20tobacco%22&f=false), 1901, p. 157.

There’s a deal more about “ship’s” at the link.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to not be a phrase, but a proper noun:

Sherlock asks "You don't mind strong tobacco?"

But Watson's response doesn't explicitly answer *Yes* or *No*. Instead, he replies, "[Not only do I not mind the smell, I myself frequently create such an aroma.] I always smoke "ship's" tobacco, myself [[a style of preparing tobacco](https://www.reed.edu/formosa/texts/Dodd1885.html) which is described as the opposite of "mild"]"

Just a possible typographical error. No punctuation, but a * or footnote would be helpful.

Comment: In other words: strong tobacco.

Comment: I expect this is correct ("ship's" means "ship's tobacco"), but I don't see why it would be a typographical error..

Comment: I think you're right about the unspoken implication of Watson's words. But why do you say that "ship's" is a proper noun?

Comment: I don't think it's a typographical error. Doyle wrapped *ship's* in quotes to indicate it was slang usage, and used single quotes because that is the convention when embedding quotes in other quotes.